# Targeting child elements in the shortest way when the first element is a jquery selector

Tags: jquery

This is a pretty trivial question.

But I'm always using jQuery `.find` - I was wondering if there was another way of avoiding always using it?

Please see my jQuery and markup below...

```
$jquerySelector = $('.parentElement');
```

--

```
<div class="parentElement">

     <div class="childElement">

          <div class="babyElement"></div>        

     </div>

     ...

</div>
```

See, normally I have to do this to find the next element...

```
$jquerySelector.find('.childElement > .babyElement')
```

Is there some how of writing this jquery selector something like this...

```
$jquerySelector > .childElement > .babyElement
```

Obviously this will not work, but you can see what I'm trying to get at.

Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Comment: `$jquerySelector.find('.childElement > .babyElement')` is the way to go, unless you want to write your own parser and add this to the JavaScript syntax (and convert it to valid JS).

Comment: How would that be better than `$jquerySelector.find()`?

Comment: @felix if find is the one then I shall continue using it. Thanks

Comment: Of course you can always optimise the selector, to maybe `$jquerySelector.find('.babyElement')` if all `.babyElement` are children of `.childElement` anyway.